# AIR: Why is stage == null?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am trying to set the scaleMode on my AIR app. which is set via stage.scaleMode. However when I try to reference stage it returns as null. I do not know why?

Here is the entire app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
            private function init():void
            {
                var s:Stage = this.stage; //<<-- this.stage == null...why??
                s.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `windowComplete` instead of `creationComplete`. Also:

> [If] you are trying to add
>   eventListeners to the stage right from
>   the start of your application
>   execution, this will only work with
>   updateComplete() and
>   applicationComplete().

Source: http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/blog/2007/02/understanding-the-flex-application-startup-event-order/

Comment: I think you mean applicationComplete instead of windowComplete?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an event listener for `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`, or the `addedToStage` mxml attribute.  You should be able to reference the stage then.

Answer (score 1):

Hell,

You could try with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication 
       xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
       creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
            private function init():void
            {
                this.systemManager.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, in both Web and AIR apps, I generally use the `applicationComplete` event to mark completion of the startup cycle, before I go looking for the `stage` object.  From the docs:

> After all components are created and
>   drawn, the Application object
>   dispatches an applicationComplete
>   event. This is the **last event
>   dispatched** during an application
>   startup.

If you wait for `applicationComplete`, you can be sure everything's ready for ya.